# What is the definition of "Cue" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

the context is:

"In Kherson, national songs were banned, speaking Ukrainian could lead to arrest and students were told they were Russian. Cue the resistance."

I don't have enoght knowledge to find a definition of "Cue" that fit in that context,
which would be one?

Comment: Please look up the word first.

Comment: @Lambie, I actually did it but I still was unable to interpret it with definition I got, maybe it is lack of skill in thinking in English. It would help to get a synonym of it

Comment: It means: give the signal to the resistance to start. It comes from: Cue the music. Meaning:  start playing it. https://strongsounds.com/blog/cue-the-music-vs-queue-the-music/

Comment: '**Cue _something_ (idiom informal humorous)** used when saying that you expect a particular thing to happen next' [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cue)

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Harvey says in comments, the meaning is,

> **Cue something (idiom informal humorous)** used when saying that you expect a particular thing to happen next

This likely derives from the usage by radio (and other) DJ's, who need to start a song playing just at the same moment the previous song ends. Therefore they (in the days when they played phonographs) had to "cue up" one turntable so that it would just be starting the song when it was "faded in".

And this likely derives from theater, where a "cue" is a line of dialog an actor listens for to signal them that the time has come for them to deliver their next line.